# Derivative tensor of $\frac{Axx^\top A}{x^\top AA x}$ with $A$ symmetric positive semi-definite

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix. I also have the following elements

- Function $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^\top A x$.
- Gradient $\nabla f(x) = -Ax$ and Jacobian $J_f(x) = -x^\top A$.
- Hessian $H_f(x) = -A$.
- Define the function $N:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
  $$
  N(x) = \frac{\nabla f(x) \nabla f(x)^\top}{\nabla f(x)^\top \nabla f(x)} = \frac{Axx^\top A}{x^\top AA x}
  $$

> How can I write the derivative of $N$ with respect to $x$ without using index notation?

The derivative will be a third-order tensor, but fundamentally I would like to be able to write down the result so that I can code it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\diff[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand\Diff[1]{\Bigl\{#1\Bigr\}}
\newcommand\trans[1]{#1^{\mathrm T}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

I hate the usual $D$ notation for total derivatives; it always creates a mess that's hard to read. Instead I'm going to use the following notation:
$$
  \diff{f}_x = \diff{f(x)}_x = Df(x),
$$$$
  \diff{f}^h_x = \diff{f(x)}^h_x = Df(x)(h).
$$
We will use the following facts:

1. The derivative of an expression is the sum of the derivatives of its parts:
   $$
      \diff{F(x,x)}^h_x = \diff{F(\dot x, x)}^h_{\dot x} + \diff{F(x, \dot x)}^h_{\dot x},
    $$
   where the notation indicates that the *undotted* $x$ is held constant; or rather, that only the *dotted* $x$ is varied. (This is actually a consequence of the chain rule.)
2. The *chain rule* says the derivative of a composition is the composition of the derivatives:
   $$
      \diff{F\circ G}_x = \diff{F}_{G(x)}\circ\diff{G}_x.
    $$
   In particular, if $f : \R \to \R$ and $g : \R^n \to \R$ then
   $$
      \diff{f\circ g}^h_x = f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\diff{g}^h_x.
    $$
3. The derivative of a linear function $L$ is itself:
   $$
      \diff{L(x)}^h_x = L(h).
    $$
4. (1) and (3) together give us the *product rule*: if $\bullet$ is any bilinear operation, then
   $$
      \Diff{F(x)\bullet G(x)}^h_{\dot x}
        = \Diff{F(\dot x)\bullet G(x)}^h_{\dot x}
          + \Diff{F(x)\bullet G(\dot x)}^h_{\dot x}
        = \diff{F}^h_x\bullet G(x) + F(x)\bullet\diff{G}^h_x.
    $$
   The last equality follows since e.g. the map $Y \mapsto Y\bullet G(x)$ is linear in $Y$. This extends just as you would expect to multilinear operations.

These facts let us easily evaluate the desired derivative:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \diff{\frac{Ax\trans xA}{\trans xA^2x}}^h_x
   &= \frac{A\diff{x\trans x}^h_xA}{\trans xA^2x}
  + Ax\trans xA\diff{\frac1{\trans xA^2x}}^h_x
\\
   &= \frac{A(h\trans x + x\trans h)A}{\trans xA^2x}
  - \frac{Ax\trans xA}{(\trans xA^2x)^2}\diff{\trans xA^2x}^h_x
\\
   &= \frac{A(h\trans x + x\trans h)A}{\trans xA^2x}
  - \frac{Ax\trans xA}{(\trans xA^2x)^2}(\trans hA^2x + \trans xA^2h)
\\
   &= \frac1{\trans xA^2x}A(h\trans x + x\trans h)A
  - 2\frac{\trans hA^2x}{(\trans xA^2x)^2}Ax\trans xA.
\end{aligned}$$
The last line follows since $\trans hA^2x = \trans xA^2 h$ since $A^2$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't the derivative be a third-order tensor taking two inputs rather than one ($h$ here)?

Comment: Okay so in the first line you've used the product rule with terms $Axx^\top A \cdot \frac{1}{x^\top A^2 x}$, as well as the fact that $A$ does not depend on $x$. 
$$
\quad 
$$
On the second line I am not sure how you obtained $\{xx^\top\}_x^h = (hx^\top + xh^\top)$ but seems like it's the product rule again, although I would think the result should be $x + x^\top$ since
$$
\{xx^\top\}_x^h = \{x\}_x^h x^\top + x\{x^\top\}_x^h = I x^\top + x I = x^\top + x
$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter You presented the function as a matrix function, so the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) is a linear map from vectors to matrices; if you think of a matrix as a second order tensor, then such a linear map is a third order tensor.

You are correct about the use of the product rule on the first line.

You're confusion with the second line seems to be from a misunderstanding of total derivatives...

Comment: ... It seems that you are probably used to thinking about the derivative of a function $f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$ as the Jacobian matrix; however, this perspective is limiting. It is more proper to think of the derivative $Df_x$ at $x$ ($\{f\}_x$ in my notation) as the *linear function* $\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ best approximating $f$ at $x$. The matrix of this linear function in the standard basis is the Jacobian. The advantage of the linear map viewpoint is that we can consider any function $f : V \to W$ between any two normed vector spaces $V, W$...

Comment: ... The function $x \mapsto xx^T$ takes vectors to matrices; so the derivative $\{xx^T\}_x$ at the point $x$ is a linear function taking vectors to matrices. The evaluation of the derivative on a vector $h$ is $\{xx^T\}^h_x$, or $D[xx^T]_x(h)$ in more traditional notation. What you're correct about is that $\{x\}_x$ is the identity *function*; but we then *evaluate* this function at $h$, giving $\{x\}^h_x = h$. Thus
$$ \{xx^T\}^h_x = \{x\}^h_xx^T + x\{x^T\}^h_x = hx^T + xh^T. $$
So the derivative $\{xx^T\}_x$ is a linear *function* taking $h$ to the RHS above...

Comment: ... So to summarize, your confusion stems from trying to think of the derivative at a point $x$ as a *value* (like a matrix), whereas it is more appropriate to think of it as a *linear function* approximating the original function at $x$.

Comment: I know that $A$ does not depend on $x$ but could you show me step by step why 
$$
\{ Axx^\top A\}_x^h = A\{xx^\top\}_x^h A
$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter Linearity and the chain rule. The total derivative of a linear function $L$ is that function itself: $$DL_x(h) = \{L(x)\}_x^h = L(h).$$ This makes sense; $DL_x$ is the best linear approximation to $L$ at $x$, so if $L$ is linear it should be just $L$. The chain rule says that for any $f, g$ such that $f\circ g$ makes sense we have $$D[f\circ g]_x(h) = [Df_{g(x)}\circ Dg_x](h) = Df_{g(x)}(Dg_x(h))$$ which it looks like I expressed in my bracket expression without $h$ by $$\{f\circ g\}_x = \{f\}_{g(x)}\circ\{g\}_x.$$

Comment: Here we have a function $g(x) = xx^\top$ and a *linear* function $f(y) = AyA$. So $$D[f\circ g]_x(h) = [f\circ Dg_x](h) = f(Dg_x(h)) = A[Dg_x(h)]A = A\{xx^\top\}_x^hA.$$

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $A$ is symmetric, one has
$$ x^\top A^2y=y^\top A^2x\in\mathbb{R}, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n. $$
Also $Axy^\top A=(Ax)(Ay)^\top$.
So, for $h\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
DN(h)(x)&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{N(x+th)-N(x)}{t}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\bigg[\frac{A(x+th)(x+th)^\top A}{(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)}-\frac{Axx^\top A}{x^\top A^2 x}\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\frac{A(x+th)(x+th)^\top Ax^\top A^2x-Axx^\top A(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)}{(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)x^\top A^2 x}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\frac{A(xx^\top+txh^\top+thx^\top+t^2hh^\top)Ax^\top A^2x-Axx^\top A(x^\top A^2x+2tx^\top A^2h+t^2h^\top A^2h))}{(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)x^\top A^2 x}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac1t\frac{A(txh^\top+thx^\top+t^2hh^\top)Ax^\top A^2x-Axx^\top A(2tx^\top A^2h+t^2h^\top A^2h))}{(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)x^\top A^2 x}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{A(xh^\top+hx^\top+thh^\top)Ax^\top A^2x-Axx^\top A(2x^\top A^2h+th^\top A^2h))}{(x+th)^\top A^2 (x+th)x^\top A^2 x}\\
&=&\frac{A(xh^\top+hx^\top)Ax^\top A^2x-2Axx^\top A(x^\top A^2h)}{(x^\top A^2 x)^2}\\
&=&\frac{x^\top A^2x(Axh^\top A+Ahx^\top A)-2Axx^\top A(x^\top A^2h)}{(x^\top A^2 x)^2}\\
&=&\frac{x^\top A^2x(Ax(Ah)^\top+Ah(Ax)^\top)-2Axx^\top A(x^\top A^2h)}{(x^\top A^2 x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: What happened going from line 2 to line 3?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff, thanks. I realize now I missed something.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tensor derivatives, so this question might be naive. But when I try to take the derivative of $f(x) = x^\top Ax~  (\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ using this technique, I get $2h^\top Ax$, where I expect "$2Ax$", without any $h$. What am I missing? I appreciate any pointers in case there is a trivial difference.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: @xpaul I don't think we need $h$ here. IMHO, your solution would be better without $h$

Comment: @Alt see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). Total derivatives are best thought of as linear maps. If $f$ takes vectors to vectors, then we can represent this linear map with a matrix, and in the standard basis this matrix is the Jacobian. In your case $Df(x)(h) = 2h^TAx = 2x^TAh$, meaning the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ is given by the linear map $Df(x)$. The matrix of this linear map is the row vector $2x^TA$.

Comment: The problem is this term $Ax(Ah)^\top+Ah(Ax)^\top$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\b{\beta}\def\d{\delta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The independent fourth-order isotropic tensors are simply permutations of the dyadic product of Kronecker deltas
$$\eqalign{
\d_{ij}\d_{kl} &= \G_{ijkl} = \F_{iljk} = \E_{ikjl} \\
}$$
but they are very handy for rearranging matrix-vector products
$$\eqalign{
yx^TM &= (y\G M^T)\,x \\
Mxy^T &= (M\E y)\,x \\
}$$
For ease of typing, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
w &= Ax &\qiq dw=A\,dx \\
B &= ww^T &\qiq dB = {w\,dw^T+dw\,w^T} \\
\b &= w\cdot w &\qiq d\b = (2w)\cdot dw \\
}$$
Write your matrix-valued function in terms of these,
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
N &= \b^{-1}B \\
dN &= \b^{-1}dB - B\b^{-2}(d\b) \\
  &= \b^{-1}{w\,dw^T} + \b^{-1}{dw\,w^T} - \b^{-1}N\LR{2w\cdot dw} \\
\b\:dN
  &= {w\,dx^T}A + A\,{dx\,w^T} - \LR{2N\star Aw}\cdot dx \\
  &= \LR{w\G A + A\E w - 2N\star Aw}\cdot dx \\
\grad{N}{x}  &= \frac{w\star A + A\E w - 2N\star(Aw)}{\b} \\
}$$
Note that juxtaposition implies a dot product (i.e. $w\G A=w\cdot\G\cdot A$) and $\star$ denotes the dyadic product. For example, the $\G$ tensor could be written in terms of the identity matrix $I$ as
$$\G = I\star I$$
or the $B$ matrix in terms of $w$ vector as
$$B = w\star w$$
I know you said that you didn't want to use index notation, but I think you are just being stubborn because it clarifies things tremendously (and is **easy** to code in Python)
$$\eqalign{
f &= Aw = A^2x \\
\grad{N_{ij}}{x_k}
 &= \frac{A_{jk}w_i+A_{ik}w_j-2N_{ij}f_k}{\b} \\
}$$